# First Lua program - Print external IP and VPN status

Tags: beginner, networking, lua

I started learning Lua yesterday and wanted to write a quick program as a practice.

It queries an external service for the IP address and country code, and naively check for the existence of network interface names used by VPNs (like Nordvpn or other). It then prints a colored output containing the country flag emoji and the IP.

I'm using [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheBoogle/716f0ba31695a7ea9faabde375768435/raw/89fff95e13e17184daf912545d5a09230b3573cd/RegionData.lua) gist for the country emojis, and the rxi-json-lua package.

Since this is the first time I'm writing more than 5 lines, I'm sure there can be at least some major improvements here.

```
local term = require "term"
local http_request = require "http.request"
local json = require "json"
local countries = require "RegionData"

local colors = term.colors
local geoip_url = "http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=countryCode,query"
local vpn_strings = {
    "nordlynx", "tun", "vpn"
}

local function get_external_ip()
    local headers, stream = assert(http_request.new_from_uri(geoip_url):go())
    local body = assert(stream:get_body_as_string())
    if headers:get ":status" ~= "200" then
        error(body)
    end
    return json.decode(body)
end

local function get_flag(country_code)
    for k, country in pairs(countries)
    do
        if k == country_code
        then
            return country["Emoji"]
        end
    end
end

local function is_vpn_on()
    local interfaces = io.popen("ip --brief a | cut -d ' ' -f 1")
    for interface in assert(interfaces:lines()) do
        for _, vpn in ipairs(vpn_strings) do
            if interface == vpn then return true end
        end
    end
    interfaces:close()
    return false
end



local function main()
    local ip_and_country = get_external_ip()
    local ip = assert(ip_and_country["query"], "Could not retrieve IP")
    local countryCode = assert(ip_and_country["countryCode"], "Could not retrieve country code")
    local flag = get_flag(string.upper(countryCode))
    if is_vpn_on() then
        print(colors.green .. flag .. ip .. colors.reset)
    else
        print(colors.red .. flag .. ip .. colors.reset)
    end
end

main()
```

Comment: moving `then` and `do` to a second line is not something you usually do in lua, they are not `{` braces, you also did it inconstantly through out your code. in `get_flag` you have the for loop `for k, country in pairs(countries)` if you are going to define `v` as `country` you should do the same for `k` and define it for what it represents as well, obviously you are using `contry_code` for a function param but maybe that could be changed to a name more descriptive and using `country_code` in place of `k`